# Problem with bool variables sharing the same values in an if else comparator

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean

I am trying to make a game with 6 (counting the tutorial) missions in it. There are 6 bool variables, one for each mission. An if else comparator checks what variables are true, and sends you to the appropriate mission. The comparator works well enough if only 1 variable is true, but it if multiple variables are true than it does not. Here is a more simplified version of the code that presents the same error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 

int main()
{
bool tutorial = true;
bool mission1 = true;
bool mission2 = true;

if (tutorial) {
    printf("It does not work");
}
else if (tutorial, mission1) {
    printf("It does work");
}
else {
    printf("It doesn't work");
}
}
```

What should happen is the program prints out "It does work". Instead, it prints out the "It doesn't work". While I am aware that if I only wanted the program to print the middle option, I would put

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 

int main()
{
bool tutorial = true;
bool mission1 = true;
bool mission2 = true;

if (tutorial, mission1) {
    printf("It does not work");
}

}
```

That would prevent you from playing more than 1 mission as well. Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the expected result of `tutorial, mission1`? You might want to read more about the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator) and what it really does.

Comment: You should be using either `tutorial && mission` or `tutorial || mission` to implement logical combination of values.

Comment: But that won't fix your problem, because `if (tutorial)` will succeed before it performs any of the other tests.

Comment: You might want to do some research about hof `if ... else if` chains really work.

Comment: Instead of lots of `if` statements you might want to consider using a truth table.

Comment: You say it prints out "It doesn't work" - I don't believe that. Please write code carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `if (tutorial, mission1)` doesn't mean what you think it means. In this statement, `tutorial, mission1` is a comma expression.

A comma expression is evaluated by evaluating what is left of the comma, throwing the result away, then evaluating what is right of the common.

So you evaluate `tutorial`, throw away the result, then evaluate `mission1`. The result is therefore the same as if you had just written `if (mission1)`.

You may have meant `if (tutorial && mission1)` or `if (tutorial || mission1)`.

Answer (score 0):

To test that tutorial is completed, and mission 1 and 2 have not been completed, you will need to write:

```
if (tutorial && !mission1 && !mission2) {
    printf("tutorial completed, mission 1 and 2 not completed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use '&&' instead of ',' so the line would look like this:

```
if (tutorial && mission1){
```

This will check if **both** turorial and mission1 are set to *true*